# Using Environment Variables in RewriteRule match - easier to maintain and smaller

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a load of rewrites to do for a very old site which has had many different directory structures. There are about 140 redirects needed, and here is an example of the structure:

```
# First file set to first destination
RewriteRule ^(dir-one|dir-two|dir-three)\/(file-one|file-two|file-three)\/?$ /destination-one [R=301,L]

# Second file set to second destination
RewriteRule ^(dir-one|dir-two|dir-three)\/(file-four|file-five|file-six)\/?$ /destination-two [R=301,L]

# Third file set to third destination
RewriteRule ^(dir-one|dir-two|dir-three)\/(file-seven|file-eight|file-nine)\/?$ /destination-three [R=301,L]

# etc etc... Same sort of thing another 137 times!
```

As you can see there is a lot of repeated info here in the initial directory match (`dir-one|dir-two|dir-three`).

I would like - if possible to make the list of directories easily updatable and wondered if Environment Variables would work. Here's what I've tried:

```
# setting the dir names in the ENV:
RewriteRule .* - [E=DIRS:"dir-one|dir-two|dir-three"]

# First file set to first destination
RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(file-one|file-two|file-three)\/?$ /destination-one [R=301,L]

# Second file set to second destination
RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(file-four|file-five|file-six)\/?$ /destination-two [R=301,L]

# Third file set to third destination
RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(file-seven|file-eight|file-nine)\/?$ /destination-three [R=301,L]
```

This is not working. I know the ENV is being set (see screenshot below) but they don't seem to be used in the RewriteRules. What am I doing wrong, is this even possible, is there a better way?

If this works I'd probably expand it to have sets of files saved as ENVs so file sets can be updated in one place too.

Thanks!

[image: Screeny showing Env Vars in phpinfo]

### Some clarification...

My example didn't show what I'm trying to achieve very well. Here's a more 'real world' example:

```
# What I have now. Note the repeated 'sections|categories|areas' part:

RewriteRule ^(sections|categories|areas)\/(car|plane|train)\/?$ /transport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(sections|categories|areas)\/(pig|cow|goat|kangaroo)\/?$ /animals [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(sections|categories|areas)\/(cheese|fish|turnips)\/?$ /food [R=301,L]
# etc etc... Same sort of thing another 137 times!
```

```
# What I'm hoping is possible. It will allow me to add or edit the
# first match (sections|categories|areas) in one place and not 140 places. 

RewriteRule .* - [E=DIRS:"sections|categories|areas"]

RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(car|plane|train)\/?$ /transport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(pig|cow|goat|kangaroo)\/?$ /animals [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:DIRS})\/(cheese|fish|turnips)\/?$ /food [R=301,L]
```

So the first match is always the same, for every rewrite. The different mapping is between the second match and the destination. i.e all the vehicles go to `/transport`, all the animals go to `/animals` etc etc.

My main aim here is to avoid repeating that first match 140 times. If my aim is stupid, please say so :)

Thank you!

Comment: match against ENV in RewriteCond not RewriteRule

Answer (score 2):

Match against `ENV` in `RewriteCond` not in `RewriteRule` like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(dir-one|dir-two|dir-three)/(.*)$ - [E=DIRS:$1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-one
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/(file-one|file-two|file-three)\/?$ /destination-one [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-two
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/(file-four|file-five|file-six)\/?$ /destination-two [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-three
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/(file-seven|file-eight|file-nine)\/?$ /destination-three [R=301,L]
```

Moreover , if you only want to redirect them to new distination and there is no relationship between the old & new uri,as i see , make them like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(dir-one|dir-two|dir-three)/(.*)/?$ - [E=DIRS:$1-$2]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-one\-(file-one|file-two|file-three)
RewriteRule ^  /destination-one [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-two\-(file-four|file-five|file-six)
RewriteRule ^  /destination-two [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^dir-three\-(file-seven|file-eight|file-nine)
RewriteRule ^    /destination-three [R=301,L]
```

**Update :**

According to your update try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(sections|categories|areas)/(.*)/?$   -   [E=DIRS:$1-$2]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^(.+)\-(car|plane|train)
RewriteRule ^  /transport  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^(.+)\-(pig|cow|goat|kangaroo)
RewriteRule ^  /animals  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIRS} ^(.+)\-(cheese|fish|turnips)
RewriteRule ^  /food  [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: Thanks for answering Mohammed. There is no relationship between directory and destination. There is a relationship between file name and destination. I may need to improve my example?

Comment: @MereDevelopment both rules will work with what you menthioned but if there are something else , let me know

Comment: If the path is this: `/dir-one/file-eight` I want it to redirect to `/destination-three`. Likewise if the `/dir-two/file-eight` should redirect to  `/destination-three`. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: @MereDevelopment ok let me change the rules

Comment: @MereDevelopment what about dir-three/file-one ? is it destination-one ?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with this. I've improved my example under the "Some clarification" section.